# My java code has no errors but why won't it run?

Tags: java

For some reason when I run my code on eclipse there is nothing showing on the screen like it should. I'm not sure what it is. I can type input into the console but that is about it. Nothing else happens. Can anyone tell me what it could be? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    Flight flight = new Flight (input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), 0);

    System.out.println("Creating first flight");
    System.out.println("What is the name of the flight?");
        String flightName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the destination of the flight?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the departure time of the flight?");
        String departureTime = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the departure gate of the flight?");
        String departureGate = input.nextLine();

    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        System.out.println("Now what would you like to do?");
        System.out.print("1. Print out a flight's info");
        System.out.print("2. Print out the number of flights through the static variable.");
        System.out.print("3. Change the departure time of a flight.");
        System.out.print("4. Change the departure gate of a flight.");
        System.out.print("5. Exit");
        int choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Which flight would you like to print the info of (1 or 2)?");
                int selection = 0;
                selection = input.nextInt();
            if (selection == 1 || selection == 2) {
                Flight.printFlight();
            } else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            } break;

        case 2: 
            System.out.println("This is the number of flights" + Flight.getNumFlights());
            break;

        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Which flight would you like to change the departure time of (1 or 2)?");
                int selection2 = 0;
                selection2 = input.nextInt();
            if (selection2 == 1 || selection2 == 2){
                System.out.println("What is the new departure time for flight " + (Flight.getNumFlights()-1));
                    String newDeptTime = input.nextLine();
                    Flight.changeDeptTime(newDeptTime);
            } else{
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            } break;

        case 4: 
            System.out.println("Which flight would you like to change the departure gate of?");
                int selection3 = input.nextInt();
            if (selection3 == 1 || selection3 == 2){
                System.out.println("What is the new departure gate for flight " + Flight.getNumFlights());
                    String newDeptGate = input.nextLine();
                    Flight.changeDeptGate(newDeptGate);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid option");
            } break;

        case 5: 
            done = true;
            break; 
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option");
            break;

        }

    }   

}

}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in and run it in debug and step through your code and see where it's breaking.

Comment: You are not getting output even after you input 4 lines for the arguments of the constructor of `Flight`, right?

Comment: Nothing will display until you enter some text since you request input on the standard input using Scanner when constructing Flight.

Comment: Oops..my eyes completely missed that...thanks everyone

Comment: @user7087153 that's what a debugger should have been able to tell you in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

its not showing anything because it is waiting for you to enter characters you want in the Flight class constructor.

As you can see here

```
Flight flight = new Flight (input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), input.nextLine(), 0);
```

execution stops at the `input.nextLine()` parts till you enter something and hit enter

P.S : its better to place some `System.out.println("enter the value")` kind of statement before the input parts to show the user what to do.funny doing this will prevent you from making this mistake you made

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Creating first flight");
        System.out.println("What is the name of the flight?");
        String flightName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the destination of the flight?");
        String destination = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the departure time of the flight?");
        String departureTime = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the departure gate of the flight?");
        String departureGate = input.nextLine();
        
        Flight flight = new Flight (flightName, destination, departureTime, departureGate, 0);

        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("Now what would you like to do?");
            System.out.print("1. Print out a flight's info");
            System.out.print("2. Print out the number of flights through the static variable.");
            System.out.print("3. Change the departure time of a flight.");
            System.out.print("4. Change the departure gate of a flight.");
            System.out.print("5. Exit");
            int choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Which flight would you like to print the info of (1 or 2)?");
                int selection = input.nextInt();
                if (selection == 1 || selection == 2) {
                    flight.printFlight();
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                } break;

            case 2: 
                System.out.println("This is the number of flights" + Flight.getNumFlights());
                break;

            case 3: 
                System.out.println("Which flight would you like to change the departure time of (1 or 2)?");
                int selection2 = input.nextInt();
                if (selection2 == 1 || selection2 == 2){
                    System.out.println("What is the new departure time for flight " + (Flight.getNumFlights()-1));
                    String new
```